How do I calculate the time it would take for the Earth to fall into the Sun?
I'm trying to calculate how long it would take the Earth to fall into the Sun if it lost all of its tangential velocity. Below is my best attempt, but no matter what I keep getting an incorrect answer (other people have calculated it at around 65 days). I broke it off into sections so it's easier to follow. I used conservation of energy to find the final velocity at the surface of the sun (section 1), set the integral of acceleration from t=0 to t=b (the time where earth hits the sun) equal to that final velocity (section 2), related the distance to time since I can't integrate acceleration as a function of distance with respect to time (section 3), then finally replaced r with t, integrated and then just used some algebra to isolate b (section 4). Idk where I went wrong, most likely in section 3, but it could be anywhere.
$r_e$ is the distance between the sun and the earth,
$r_s$ is the radius of the sun,
$M$ is the sun's mass,
$m$ is the earth's mass,
$b$ is the time $t$ where the earth hits the sun (what I'm solving for),
$C_v$ and $C$ are both constants of integration
Section 1

$\Delta E_K=\Delta U_G$
$\frac 12m{v_f}^2=-\int_{r_e}^{r_s} \frac {GMm}{r^2}\ dr$
$\frac 12{v_f}^2=-\int_{r_e}^{r_s} \frac {GM}{r^2}\ dr$
$\frac 12{v_f}^2=1.89848005\cdot 10^{11}$
$v_f=6.161947827\cdot10^5\; m/s$

Section 2

$\int_0^b a\ dt=v_f-v_0$
$\int_0^b \frac {GM}{r^2}\ dt=v_f$
$\int_0^b \frac {GM}{r^2}\ dt=6.161947827\cdot10^5$

Section 3

$\frac {GM}{r^2}=\frac {d^2r}{dt^2}$
$GM\ dt^2=r^2\ d^2r$
$(GMt+C_v)\ dt=\frac 13r^3\ dr$
$GMt+C_v = \frac 13r^3 \cdot \frac {dr}{dt}$
$C_v=0$
$GMt\ dt=\frac 13r^3\ dr$
$\frac 12GMt^2+C=\frac 1{12}r^4$
$C=\frac 1{12}{r_e}^4$
$C=4.17392968\cdot 10^{43}$
$\frac 12GMt^2+4.17392968\cdot 10^{43}=\frac 1{12}r^4$
$r^2=\sqrt {6GMt^2+5.00871562\cdot 10^{44}}$

Section 4

$\int_0^b \frac {GM}{\sqrt {6GMt^2+5.00871562\cdot 10^{44}}}\ dt=6.161947827\cdot 10^5$
$\int_0^b \frac 1{\sqrt {6GMt^2+5.00871562\cdot 10^{44}}}\ dt=4.64170473\cdot 10^{-15}$
$3.54329\cdot 10^{-11} \sinh^{-1} {(1.26101\cdot 10^{-12} \cdot b)}=4.64170473\cdot 10^{-15}$
$\sinh^{-1} {(1.26101\cdot 10^{-12} \cdot b)}=1.31\cdot 10^{-4}$
$1.26101\cdot 10^{-12} \cdot b=\sinh {(1.13\cdot 10^{-4})}$
$1.26101\cdot 10^{-12} \cdot b=1.13\cdot 10^{-4}$
$b=1.038848654\cdot 10^8\;sec=1202\;days=3.294\;yrs$


Sorry, "check my work" questions are off-topic here. We do have some related questions, eg https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/602996/123208 but they usually get closed pretty quickly.

This question is similar to: The Time That 2 Masses Will Collide Due To Newtonian Gravity. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Celestial mechanics questions are permitted on https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/ but you're asking people to do a fair bit of work to check all that stuff... Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_trajectory

You seem to have forgotten a minus on the force in section 3. Notice that your solution for $r(t)$ is increasing with time. I don't know if that's the only mistake tho

Also, the method in section 3 is not correct. You cannot go from $\frac{d^2 r}{d t^2} = x$ to $ dr^2 = x dt^2$. Notice that the units of these two equations are not consistent! IN other words, in section 3 the units are inconsistent (and the equations therefore wrong) from eq. 2 and on.

Conservation of energy gives a first-order differential equation for $r(t)$: $$\frac12 m\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2=\frac{GMm}{r}-\frac{GMm}{r_0}.$$ (This assumes the Sun is so massive that it doesn’t move, which is a very good approximation.) Solve for $dt$ in terms of $dr$ and integrate to get the freefall time.

Section 2 is mostly irrelevant and sections 3 and 4 are mostly wrong.
